# Updating an array in Firebase firestore. Unsupported field value: a custom ArrayUnionTransform object

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose I have the following code:

```
const washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

await washingtonRef.set({ regions: [] });

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
await washingtonRef.update({
  regions: FieldValue.arrayUnion({a: 0})
});

const doc = await washingtonRef.get();
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log("No such document!");
} else {
  console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
}
```

What ought to happen is that "Document data:" along with the actual document data (`{a: 0}`) gets printed. This is the case when I am using firebase-admin. Under normal circumstances, I am using Firestore with Google Cloud Function, and so I use `initializeApp()` and get reference to the `db` with `getFirestore()`, both of which are from `firebase-admin`.

However, when I try to write tests with Jest, any API calls that reads or modifies the database never resolves. I figured that `initializeApp()` and `getFirestore()` is not correct for the test environment. After reading [Build unit tests guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests#run_local_unit_tests_with_the_version_9_javascript_sdk), I decided to go with version 9 JavaScript SDK.

While everything seems to be fine, calling update with `FieldValue.arrayUnion` throws the following error:

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom ArrayUnionTransform object (found in field  in document )

**Code snippets**

```
beforeAll(async () => {

process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT = "my-project-id";
process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = "127.0.0.1:8086";

testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
  projectId: projectId,
  firestore: {
    rules: readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 8086
  }
});

const unauth = testEnv.unauthenticatedContext();
db = unauth.firestore();

connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "127.0.0.1", 8086);

const washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

await washingtonRef.set({ regions: [] });

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
await washingtonRef.update({
  regions: FieldValue.arrayUnion({a: 0})
});

const doc = await washingtonRef.get();
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log("No such document!");
} else {
  console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
}

})
```